# Error with read.table

Tags: r, dataframe

I am struggling with a confusing error in R. I have dataset including many columns. When I read it, I see error message such as "Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,".

```
    > data=read.table(file("D:/R/data.txt"), header=T)
    Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
    line 1 did not have 26 elements
```

Thus, I tried the below,

```
    > data=read.table(file("D:/R/data.txt"), fill=T, header=F)
    > head(data)
      V1      V2      V3      V4      V5        V6        V7         V8
    1 Year      Na     NH4       K      Mg        Ca        Cl        NO3
    2 2009 40.9311  89.072 65.4617 48.5279 3091.9586 52.782114 173.414523
    3 2009 19.8996 75.3554  22.219 11.8805  223.5573  28.51786 219.186039
```

OK, anyway, R read my data. Then I want plot, so I remove 1st row, which is my header actually.

```
    > data<-data[-c(1), ]
    > head(data)
      V1      V2      V3      V4      V5        V6        V7         V8
   2 2009 40.9311  89.072 65.4617 48.5279 3091.9586 52.782114 173.414523

   > boxplot(V20~factor(V1), data=data, main="")
     Error in boxplot.default(split(mf[[response]], mf[-response]), ...) : 
     adding class "factor" to an invalid object
   > a<-aggregate(V20~V1, data=data, mean) 
    There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

Initially, I just wanted to read my data set and aggregate each column as a function of year (first colulmn). But I see the error message, which might ask me to make my data into data frame. Then I am lost how to handle it. Is there any way to read my data with header and simply plot a box plot and aggregate data?

Comment: You have some confusion here. What is `cfa` and what is `data`? Also, perhaps show us the first few lines of your "data.txt" file to see exactly what's going on.

Comment: The `count.fields` function is also useful for this sort of problem. It tells you how many columns R thinks there are in each row of data.  Waht does `count.fields("D:/R/data.txt")` return?  (Also, you don't need to call the `file` function.  `read.table` accepts a string to the file path.)

Comment: It could be that your separators are different for headers and data.

Comment: Thanks a lot, all of you. Sorry for my confusing use of cfa and data. I changed it. Richie, count.fields is very useful function. Applying that function, I found my problems. I used separators differently for headers, as mentioned by Laurik. Thanks all! :)

Comment: @LauriK can you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your separators are different for headers and data.

Posting this as an answer, turned out to be the correct solution :)